# Turn flat query into 2D table

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I have a database table where each row has (among other things), Date, Product and Quantity fields:

```
Date       Prod Qty
06/01/2018 ABC 10
06/02/2018 ABC 5
06/03/2018 ABC 3
...
06/01/2018 DEF 2
06/02/2018 DEF 8
06/03/2018 DEF 11
...
06/01/2018 GHI 1
```

I would like to output a 2D table grouped by dates and products:

```
            ABC DEF GHI
06/01/2018  10  2    1
06/02/2018  5   8    2
06/03/2018  3   11   4
```

I can see an ugly and un-LINQ-y way to do this (find distinct lists of dates and products, make a 2D array with dimensions matching these lists, manually go through the list to find the quantity associated with that row and column.) But is there something more elegant?

The number of products is large, so manually joining a bunch of queries doesn't seem viable.

Comment: FYI if you want to do a search this is known as a Pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pivot table like code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Prod", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {DateTime.Parse("06/01/2018"), "ABC", 10});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {DateTime.Parse("06/02/2018"), "ABC", 5});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {DateTime.Parse("06/03/2018"), "ABC", 3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {DateTime.Parse("06/01/2018"), "DEF", 2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {DateTime.Parse("06/02/2018"), "DEF", 8});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {DateTime.Parse("06/03/2018"), "DEF", 11});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {DateTime.Parse("06/01/2018"), "GHI", 1});

            string[] uniqueProducts = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Prod")).OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            foreach (string prod in uniqueProducts)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(prod, typeof(int));
            }

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date")).GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date).ToList();

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Date"] = group.Key;
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    newRow[row.Field<string>("Prod")] = row.Field<int>("Qty");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```